# SQL + Ajax update limit for each day

Tags: php

I created a sort of voting website with PHP and a MYSQL database. People can vote on id's that are in the database and the amount of likes goes up.

When you click on a button the likes of that specific id goes up by one. This is done through Ajax and sql.

Is it possible to set a limitation of the amount of likes an id can have for each day. For instance each id can update only 10 times each day. And the next day another 10 times.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put condition in ajax code.
Before inserting record in DB for vote first check the total number of vote received for that ID on current day.
If it is equal to 10 then skip the operation or else increase the vote.

You have to put this conditions in this file /10jaar/views/submissions.php

Not a big deal i think so.

Comment: I have put a bit of my code above here. Do have an example of how to achieve that. Thanks for you comment!